# How to end a while Loop via user input

Tags: java, if-statement, while-loop

```
package cst150zzhw4_worst;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class CST150zzHW4_worst {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    //Initialize Variables
    double length; // length of room
    double width; // Width of room
    double price_per_sqyd; // Total carpet needed price
    double price_for_padding; // Price for padding
    double price_for_installation; // Price for installation
        String input; // User's input to stop or reset program
    double final_price; // The actual final price
        boolean repeat = true;

    // Create a Scanner object for keyboard input.
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        while (repeat)
        {   
        //User Input

    System.out.println("\n" +"What is the length of the room?: ");
    length = keyboard.nextInt();

    System.out.println("What is the width of the room?: ");
    width = keyboard.nextInt();

    System.out.println("What is the price of the carpet per square yard?: ");
    price_per_sqyd = keyboard.nextDouble();

        System.out.println("What is the price for the padding?: ");
        price_for_padding = keyboard.nextDouble();

        System.out.println("What is the price of the installation?: ");
        price_for_installation = keyboard.nextDouble();

        final_price = (price_for_padding + price_for_installation + price_per_sqyd)*((width*length)/9);

        keyboard.nextLine(); //Skip the newline

        System.out.println("The possible total price to install the carpet will be $" + final_price + "\n" + "Type 'yes' or 'no' if this is correct: ");
        input = keyboard.nextLine();

        } 
    }
}
```

How would I make it so when the user says yes the program stop and if the user says no then the program just repeats? I don't know why I'm having so much trouble. I've searched for well over 4 hours. I am only supposed to use a while loop, I think.

Answer (score 4):

You have to assign `repeat` in your `while`-loop so it becomes `false` if the user says `yes`:

```
repeat = !input.equalsIgnoreCase("yes");
```

Answer (score 2):

You just need to set `repeat` to true or false based on user input. So in the end, compare `input` with yes or no. Something like this would work for you :

```
if ("yes".equals(input)) 
 repeat = true; // This would continue the loop
else 
 repeat = false; // This would break the infinite while loop
```

Comment: `repeat = "yes".equals(input);` ... avoid branching.

Answer (score 1):

```
    boolean repeat = true;

   // Create a Scanner object for keyboard input.
     Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    while (repeat)
    {   
       -----------------------
       -------------------------
       System.out.println("Do you want to continue:");
       repeat = keyboard.nextBoolean();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

you also if you want your code to be more systematic , go and search about the interrupt , specially thread interrupt , these answers above is correct , find the more organic code and implement it

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `break` statement to exit a while loop.

```
while (...) {

   input = ...;
   if (input.equals("Y")) {
     break;
   }
}
```

Comment: Don't use == to compare string values

Comment: Sorry...too much C# coding for me :)