# Java Program Loop

Tags: java, loops

i want to be able to have the program to start over (show the enter loan amount prompt) after typing 'y' when asked "to calculate the program again" or end program if user input 'n'.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MonthlyMortgageRate {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        double Amount;
        double Rate;
        double Months;
        double outputNum1;

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Enter loan amount:");
        Amount = in.nextDouble();

        System.out.print("Enter rate:");
        Rate = in.nextDouble() / 100 / 12;

        System.out.print("Enter year:");
        Months = in.nextDouble() * 12;

        outputNum1 = Rate * Amount / (1 - Math.pow(1 + Rate, -Months));

        if (Amount <= 0)
            System.out.println("You must enter positive numeric data!");
        else
            System.out.printf("Monthly payment is: $ %.2f%n", outputNum1);

        System.out.println("would you like to calculate again?(y/n)");
    }


    private static double inputNum2(double d) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
    }
}
```

Comment: Basically, you need to loop and learn [How to end a while Loop via user input](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18975208/how-to-end-a-while-loop-via-user-input)

Comment: And what's so hard about writing a loop ?

Comment: and the loop? have u tried anything?

Answer (score 2):

Basically you need to loop the code in main.

```
do {
    // your code here
    System.out.println("would you like to calculate again?(y/n)");
} while (in.next().equalsIgnoreCase("y"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the following to your code:

```
Boolean doagain = true;
// after Scanner in
while(doagain)
{
// your code
System.out.println("would you like to calculate again?(y/n)");
if ( in.next().toLowerCase().equals("n") ) doagain = false;
} // end while
// your code
```

Enjoy Cliff