# Need to have a string "Enter a number: " repeat

Tags: java, for-loop, while-loop, tostring

As the title said I need to enter a string "Enter a number: " repeat itself after I've entered multiple values until I enter "DONE."

So for example it should look like this:

> ```
> Enter a number:
> 4
> Enter a number:
> 53
> Enter a number:
> DONE //closes program
> ```

This is a small part to a larger program and granted I know its simple, but I cant figure this out :[

What I'm guessing and been trying is a public static class with a toString method. But I can only get one "Enter a number: " printed once.

```
Enter a number:
4
53
DONE //closes program
```

Thanks in advance.

Some code I have for this part would be:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class EnterANumba
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {     
     while() //Stuck here
     {
     System.out.println("Enter a number:");
     }
     Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);    
     String word=null;          
     while (scanner.hasNextLine()) 
     {         
         word = scanner.nextLine();                  
         if (word != null) 
         {                         
              word = word.trim();                       
              if (word.equalsIgnoreCase("done")) 
              {      
                  break;                                  
              }                          
          }
           else 
          {
             break;                                   
          }
 }
```

Comment: You may have a lessons about **loop** in your upcoming classes.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to end a while Loop via user input](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18975208/how-to-end-a-while-loop-via-user-input)

Comment: Can you show us some of your codes?

Comment: @SpringLearner sure thing.

Comment: I assume you are new to programming so here's an algorithm will look like: use a boolean to control the loop, change boolean to false if input is "DONE", otherwise do nothing because your boolean variable is true by default. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

I guess this following code snippet may help you.

public class Main {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner s=new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter a number:");
    while(!(s.next().equalsIgnoreCase("DONE"))){

        System.out.println("Enter a number:");
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

try asking for the 1st time and then make a loop where you validate the input and ask until the condition is met...

## Example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please enter a number:");
    while (!("done".equalsIgnoreCase(scanner.next()))) {

        System.out.println("Enter a number:");
    }
    System.out.println("Enter a number:we are done....");
}
```