# How to stop scanning after I input a certain line?

Tags: java, loops, input

I want to build a program that only stops scanning for strings until after I input "0" in the console, how do I do that?

I assume I can use do while loop, but I don't know what to put in the while() condition.

```
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    do {

        String line = scan.nextLine(); 

        //do stuff

    } while(); //what do i put in here to stop scanning after i input "0"
```

Thanks in advance, I'm new to Java and OOP in general.

Comment: Put in there some condition ot check if `line` is different from "0". You need to declare the variable outside of the loop tho.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I exit a while loop in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7951690/how-do-i-exit-a-while-loop-in-java)

Comment: can you provide an example for exactly what you want

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to end a while Loop via user input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18975208/how-to-end-a-while-loop-via-user-input)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a while loop instead of a do-while loop. Define a String that will be initialized inside the while loop. On each iteration we assign the String to Scanner#nextLine and check if that line is not equal to 0. If it is, the while-loop prevents iteration.

```java
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        String line;

        while (!(line = scan.nextLine()).equals("0")) {
            System.out.println("line: " + line);
        }
```

Comment: nextLine() still takes 0

Comment: i think he want to enter input until 0 is pressed , so your code still let the zero enter , because , nextLine() will take entire line, doesn't matter what condition you appy, please see my answer

Comment: Eh, he said **until after I input 0** which means at some point he expects to input 0. This will allow him to process that input until 0 is provided.

Comment: so did i get it incorrect, i still don't get it, he didn't provide an example, i answered according to what i understood

Comment: Yea, I would presume that it's a matter of misunderstanding the question.

Comment: let me ask for an example from OP

Comment: Absolutely, it's always a good idea to ask for clarity. I could be wrong.

Comment: I figured it out by just using if(line.equals("0")) break; statement inside the while loops, for some reason your '!' is not working on me

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to use any loop , as you said you want to stop input when 0 is pressed by default for nextLine() the input stops when user press the enter key because it is the delimiter , so just change the delimiter

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
scanner.useDelimiter("0");   //regex
String s = scanner.next(); // no matter what user enters the s will contain the input before 0
```

Comment: The user said **until I stop scanning for Strings** so it is implied they want multiple String values, meaning some type of looping mechanics is required. Not a singular line.